# Raphael text and Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, svg, positioning, raphael

I've been using Raphael 2.0.1 on a project lately and I just was doing some cross-browser checks and saw that text (and only text…) is not displaying correctly in Safari.
What appears to be happening is the 's dy is being set to the same value as the 's 'y' value.

Here is an excerpt of the rendered html specific to what I am talking about:

```
<text style="font: normal normal normal 12px/normal 'Helvetica Neue'; text-anchor: start; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0.7; " x="96" y="15" text-anchor="start" font="12px &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#17d6c6" opacity="0.7">
<tspan dy="15">U.S Population - Blood</tspan>
<tspan dy="10.799999999999999" x="96">Type Breakdown</tspan>
</text>
```

And here is my js for the text in question:

```
var type_text = lab_culture_type.text(96, 15, 'U.S Population - Blood\nType Breakdown');
    type_text.attr({'fill':'#17D6C6', 'font':'12px "Helvetica Neue"', 'text-anchor':'start','cursor':'pointer'});
```

As I said the y and cy values are only being tied together in Safari. I have a lot of text being rendered by Raphael so setting class names for each one is kind of out of the question (well im trying to avoid it as it seems sloppy to me). I've tried targeting the dy but can't seem to get it. BTW, I am using Raphael alongside jQuery.

Using FF: 9.0.1 and Safari: 5.1.2 both on OS X.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If I could somehow insure the 'dy' was always set to '0' I would be done. I just can't get to it.

Comment: I had the same issue when using bootstrap pop-up

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Make sure the container has been inserted before you call Raphael.

```
var container = $('<div></div>'),
    r;

// Insert
$('body').append(container);

r = Raphael($container[0], 800, 600);

// Add text etc, dy on tspan should be correct...
```

If you do it the other way around the tspan's dy attribute will be messed up (like you have observed). I found it happened in all webkit browsers.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, thanks.
I ended up just implementing html text to finish the project however, I will try this out and see if it helps.
Cheers for the info!